# Convert Xamarin Native IOS swift UI to MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui, .net-8.0, xamarin-native

I have a Project, which is having Xamarin native IOS, and IOS designs are done in swift and Xcode, is there any way to convert this Project into MAUI?

Do I need to totally Rewrite the project or just need to Follow some steps to Convert this swift ui as XAML and use the other cs Files as it is?

Comment: Storyboards cannot be automatically converted to XAML, *AFAIK*, so you'll have to do that by hand. For the rest of the code: It depends. Usually, it should be possible to reuse *some* of the code in the iOS-specific part of the MAUI app (in the *Platforms* folder). Either way, converting from a **Xamarin** (not *Xamarin.Forms*) app will be more work than converting from a **Xamarin.Forms** app to MAUI, which already requires quite some time depending on the complexity of the app.

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to convert the project to use the cross-platform approach using XAML or do you simply want to keep maintaining the app as-is but also upgrade it to MAUI?

Answer (score 0):

Native Xamarin.iOS projects can upgrade to .Net for iOS without needing to convert to the full Maui UI. You don't need to rewrite the native UI in Xaml to use it with .Net for iOS. You'll need to update the project to SDK style, and you may need to update some of the cs code, but most should work as is.

For more information, you can check the official document [Upgrade from Xamarin to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/?view=net-maui-8.0).

> Xamarin projects can run on .NET after completing an upgrade process.
>
> To upgrade an app from Xamarin to .NET:
>
> - All projects do need to become SDK-style.
> - Projects don't need to be rewritten.
> - Multi-project solutions don't need to become a multi-targeted single    project.

For more information, see [Upgrade Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and Xamarin.Mac projects to .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects?view=net-maui-8.0).